# How can I get the value of the radio button after click

Tags: javascript

How will I get the value of the radio button after clicked on the button?

```
document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', function(){

        var kleuren = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio');

        for (var i in kleuren) {
            kleuren[i].onclick = function(){
                document.getElementById('divResult'). innerHTML = 
                'Gekozen kleur: ' + this.value;
            }
        }

        });

<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="rood" checked />Rood</br />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="blauw"  />Blauw</br />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="geel"  />Geel</br />
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="groen"  />Groen</br />

<button id="btnKnop1">Check de waarde!</button>

<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Now it depends on click on the radio button, but I'd to depend on click on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be be the inner click event on the radio button. If you change the loop to an `if` statement checking if it's checked then you can output the value on the button click:

```js
document.getElementById('btnKnop1').addEventListener('click', function(){

        var kleuren = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio');

        for (var i in kleuren) {
            
            if (kleuren[i].checked === true) {
            document.getElementById('divResult'). innerHTML = 
                'Gekozen kleur: ' + kleuren[i].value;
            }
        
       }

});
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="rood" checked />Rood</br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="blauw"  />Blauw</br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="geel"  />Geel</br>
<input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="groen"  />Groen</br>

<button id="btnKnop1">Check de waarde!</button>

<div id="divResult"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please consider using english-named variables, it will improve readability by a lot.

Second of all, line

```
var kleuren = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio');
```

has a typo, it's missing a closing square bracket - `]`.

To check a checkbox/radio button value you can use `checkbox.checked`, where `checkbox` is your DOM object selected by `querySelector`.

Comment: Really, the english variable thing isn't relevant. Calling it "horse" or "x" would not make it any clearer in this naive context. In fact I was curious what "kleuren" meant.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically already doing it. When you click the button, in the click handler for the button, just grab the radio button element using a selector (either class or id), with a "querySelector" call (just like you're doing). Inspect that element for whatever property makes sense (probably "checked").

Something like:

```
<button onclick="onClick ()">Click Me</button>

...

onClick () {
const kleuren = document.querySelector ( [mySelectorByIDorClass, etc.] );
console.log ( kleuren.checked );
}
```

See here:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_checked.asp

Answer (score 0):

The checked property will tell you whether the element is selected:

```
if (document.getElementById('id').checked) {
    var variable = document.getElementById('id').value;
}
```